# How to run Javascript code after $.post regardless if it succeeds or not?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have the following function to check whether a product can be added to cart and do things after

```
// Add item to cart
function add_cart_item(variant_id, qty, callback) {
  $.post('/cart/add.js', {
    quantity: qty,
    id: variant_id
  }, null, "JSON")
  .done(function() {
    // Do stuff after product is added to cart
    // Update cart product count
    refresh_cart('add', variant_id);
    
    // Callback
    if (typeof callback === 'function') { 
      callback();
    }
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR) {
    handle_xhr(jqXHR);
  });
}
```

Elsewhere I replace the "Buy now" button text with a preloader until the request is complete, then return the original text with the following code

```
add_cart_item(variant.id, $('.quantity', $parent).val(), function(){
  // Enable button
  $button.prop('disabled', false).html($button_html);
});
```

This works until the `post` method in `add_cart_item` function fails (usually with 422 response), in which the button portion is no longer executed and is stuck in preloader state.

How can I make the button part of the code run regardless of whether the function succeeds or not, but still wait for it to complete the request before executing?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is jQuery.

Use `.always` instead of `.done`.

From https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

> The jqXHR.done() (for success), jqXHR.fail() (for error), and
> jqXHR.always() (for completion, whether success or error; added in
> jQuery 1.6) methods take a function argument that is called when the
> request terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own silly mistake. Turns out .fail doesn't prevent function callback, what does prevent it however is not having the code to execute the callback in the .fail portion of my function. So this fixed the issue:

```
function add_cart_item(variant_id, qty, callback) {
  $.post('/cart/add.js', {
    quantity: qty,
    id: variant_id
  }, null, "JSON")
  .done(function() {
    // Do stuff after product is added to cart
    // Update cart product count
    refresh_cart('add', variant_id);
    
    // Callback
    if (typeof callback === 'function') { 
      callback();
    }
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR) {
    handle_xhr(jqXHR);

   // Callback
    if (typeof callback === 'function') { 
      callback();
    }
  });
}
```